Kinova Gen3 Arm related：Can anybody tell me how to transfer the plug in picture 1 to the plug in picture 2?
enter image description here
**A.jpg

I am using a Kinova Gen3 Arm and some part of components get lost
The Power source only remain an adaptor
I think I need to find a way to transfer the plug of the adaptor to the connector which can power this arm. I don't know what it is.
Or is there a way I can directly power my kinova arm?
